# Minimize array traversal conditional statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I have a situation where I'm traversing an array of objects in variable directions, accessing a callback property (it may be undefined), and executing it. What is the best way to minimize the code for this logic pattern? It shows up a lot in my code and its getting way too bloated.

```js
var source, callback;

if (dir === "up" && index > 0) {
  source = index - 1;
}
else if (dir === "down") {
  source = index;
}

if source && callback = myArray[source].callback {
  callback();
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `and` isn't Javascript right?  It would likely be `&&`.

Comment: If you use this over and over, then why not put the logic in a shared function and call it as needed.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, i copied this from coffeescript and just missed it. I've updated it now.

Comment: The variations from one case of this pattern to another are enough that I don't think a function is preferable. It's possible that it is but I'm most interested in seeing if it can be done without one.

Comment: Not much we can do to turn this into shared code if you won't show the various cases that need to be handled.  If you just want to reduce the number of characters to express this logic, then you should probably take it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but I don't see much to be gained.